# How to programatically delete a native contact using the contact number in android?

Tags: android, mobile, android-contacts

I have a requirement to delete a contact from the native contacts list using just the MSISDN. At the moment, I'm going through all the contacts and doing a match on the number to get the name. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Here is my code:

getting all the native contacts:

```
override fun nativeContactList(): Single<List<NativeContact>> {
    val contacts = ArrayList<NativeContact>()
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC")
    val normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = HashSet<String>();
    val indexOfNormalizedNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER)
    val indexOfDisplayName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val indexOfDisplayNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
    cursor.use { cursor ->
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val normalizedNumber = cursor.getString(indexOfNormalizedNumber)
            if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)) {
                val displayName = cursor.getString(indexOfDisplayName)
                val displayNumber = cursor.getString(indexOfDisplayNumber)
                Timber.d("Existing contact: $displayName $displayNumber")
                contacts.add(NativeContact(displayName, displayNumber, null, null))
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return Single.fromCallable {
        contacts
    }
}
```

once I have the list of native conntacts, I iterate through the list and look for a match in order to get the name:

```
   Observable.fromIterable(nativeContacts)
            .subscribeOn(processScheduler)
            .subscribe(object : DisposableObserver<NativeContact>() {
                override fun onComplete() {
                    Timber.d("Finished going thorough contacts")
                }


                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Timber.d("Warning: exception occurred while looping through native contacts list")
                }

                override fun onNext(nativeContact: NativeContact) {
                    if (contactToDelete.number == nativeContact.phoneNumber) {
                        contactToDelete.firstName = nativeContact.name
                        deprovisionContact(contactToDelete)
                    }
                }

            })
```

and after I have a name and a number, I delete the contact:

```
        public Completable deleteContact(final ContactToDelete contactToDelete) {
        return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                Timber.d("Attempting to delete " + contactToDelete.getNumber() + " " + contactToDelete.getName());
                Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(contactToDelete.getNumber()));
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
                try {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
String name = contactToDelete.getName();
  if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                                context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                                Timber.d("deleted " + contactToDelete.getNumber() + " " + contactToDelete.getName());
                            }

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Timber.e("Error while attempting to delete contact " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? ie not to loop through the contacts list every time we want to delete a contact? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot a few issues here.

1. First of all your requirement is not clear, are you meant to delete ALL contacts that contain this phone number? A phone number is not a unique identifier, it can be shared by more then one contact, are you supposed to delete all of those contacts?
2. You're iterating through all contacts just to get the name? Why would you need a name to delete a contact, that is also a non-unique identifier, there might be multiple contacts with the same name AND same number.
3. You're doing too many steps here, I see you're already familiar with the PHONE_LOOKUP table, you simply need to use it in order to delete the contacts with the requested phone number.

Code example (not tested):

```
// get all contact-ids of all deletion candidates
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
String[] projection = new String[]{ PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID };
Cursor idsCursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null); 

// iterate the cursor and delete all the contact-ids one-by-one
while (idsCursor != null && idsCursor.moveToNext()) {
    Long contactId = idsCursor.getLong(0);
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    context.getContentResolver().delete(contactUri, null, null);
}
if (idsCursor != null) {
    idsCursor.close();
}
```